# How can I make terminal prompt on jquery terminal save in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, web, project, jquery-terminal

Im trying to find a way that when you try this command:

```
custprmt: function(pstr, ifbold) {

if(ifbold === '-makebold') {
     localStorage.setItem('myNEWprompt', pstr);
this.set_prompt('[[b;var;]' + pstr +' ')
}

else  {
             localStorage.setItem('myNEWprompt', pstr);
       this.set_prompt(pstr +' ')
       }

},
```

It will make a custom prompt based off what the user types, and save it to local storage.
Then by using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if (myNEWprompt) {
      set_prompt(myNEWprompt)
       } else {
        set_prompt('guest$ ')
      }
      });
```

It will load the custom prompt on page load. My issue is that the second set of code isnt loading the prompt that is saved. I feel like it might be because of the `set_prompt` but im not sure, ive tried `this.set_prompt` and `prompt:`  but none works. Im not really sure what to do anymore, and I dont know if its even possible, so please help, your assistance will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to have command with options. There is helper methods for that `$.terminal.parse_options()`.

You're code can look like this:

```js
$('body').terminal({
  custprmt(...args) {
    const options = $.terminal.parse_options(args);
    if (options._.length !== 1) {
      this.error('Usage: custprmt prompt [options]');
    } else {
      let prompt = options._[0];
      if (options.makebold) {
        prompt = '[[b;white;]' + prompt + ']';
      }
      localStorage.setItem('myNEWprompt', prompt);
      this.set_prompt(prompt);
    }
  }
}, {
    checkArity: false,
    greetings: false,
    completion: true,
    prompt: localStorage.getItem('myNEWprompt') ?? 'guest$ '
});
```

but note that options with long names require a double dash. So you need to type:

```
custprmt "hello> " --makebold
```

Quotes for the prompt are needed if you want to have a space after the prompt.

Here is a [working demo](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/dyagYMv).

When you parse options you have a similar syntax to [Yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs-parser).

You have an object with each option as a field if the option is a flag it has a true or false value or if it's an option with an argument it has a string as a value. In case of a boolean option like in your case you can use a second argument to indicate that the option is boolean so it can be used before the normal argument.

Example:

```js
$.terminal.parse_options(args, {boolean: ["makebold"]});
```

When using this you can have a command that looks like this:

```
custprmt --makebold "hello> "
```

And the output will be the same, the makebold option will be a boolean flag.

Comment: Ayooooo thx mate it worked :>